# Continuity of vectorial function

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}$ a given function and $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ the function  defined by:
$$g(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x,y) & \text{if $x\leq 0$}\\
(x,y+f(x)) & \text{if $x>0$}
\end{cases}$$
 Questions: What is the condition on $f$ for:

1) The continuity of $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

2) The differentiability of $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

My answers:

1) Continuity:  The problem is in the point $(0,y)$. For the the first component no problem. The problem is in the second. We must prove that 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_0)}g(x,y)=g(0,y_0).$$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_0),x\leq0}g(x,y)=(0,y_0)$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,y_0),x>0}g(x,y)=(0,y_0+f(0))$$
Then, $y_0=y_0+f(0)$. This implies that $f(0)=0$. Does this solution is correct?

2) Differentiability: I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Let's introduce notations $g(x,y)=\begin{cases} g_n(x,y)=(x,y) & x\le 0 \\g_p(x,y)=(x,y+f(x)) & x>0\end{cases}$

On their respective domain $g_n$ is $C^\infty$ and $g_p$ has the same regularity than $f$.

So the only problem is in a neighborhood of $x=0$.

Your work for point (1) is correct, except the condition is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=0$ because the problem states $f$ is defined only in $\mathbb R^*_+$, you can't speak of $f(0)$ only about the limit.

For point (2) we of course need that (1) is verified.

So let's study what happen in the point $(0,y_0)$.

Note: $\frac{\partial g_n}{\partial y}(x,y)=(x,1)=\frac{\partial g_p}{\partial y}(x,y)$ so everything continuous there.

We are only interested in 
$\begin{cases} 
h\le 0 & \displaystyle\frac{g(h,y_0)-g(0,y_0)}h = \frac{(h,y_0)-(0,y_0)}h=(1,0)\\
h>0    & \displaystyle\frac{g(h,y_0)-g(0,y_0)}h = \frac{(h,y_0+f(h))-(0,y_0)}h=(1,\frac{f(h)}h)\end{cases}$

The condition for differentiability of $g$ in $(0,y_0)$ is $f(h)=o(h)$ near $0$.

If we want $g$ to be $C^1$ then we need the stronger condition : $f$ is $C^1$  and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=0$ (obtained by studying continuity for $\frac{\partial g_n}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial g_p}{\partial x}$).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.